# c# comparing int values (in TextBox & TextBlock)

Tags: c#

I'm creating a ranking system (in c# Windows 8 App) that works as follow:

**Example :Score of the match = 2 - 1**

Player A: Forecast = 1 - 1 (1 point for entering 1 correct score input)

Player B: Forecast = 0 - 2 (0 points)

Player C: Forecast = 3 - 0 (3 points for saying that team won)

Player D: Forecast = 2 - 0 (4 points: 3 points for saying the team won + 1 point correct score input)

Player E: Forecast = 2 - 1 (5 points: 3 points for saying the team won + 2 points correct score input

The score of the match is entered in 2 **TextBoxs** (MatchScore1 and MatchScore2)
The player's forecast is in 2 **TextBlocks** (Forecast1 and Forecast2)
When Clicked on a button it calculates the score and displays it in a TextBlock (AmountPoints)

What I've done at the moment:

```
  private void btnBereken_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int score = 0;
        // Check: Correct input score
        if (Forecast1.Text == MatchScore1.Text)
        {
           score += 1;
           AmountPoints.Text = score.ToString();
        }
        // Check: Correct input score
        if (Forecast2.Text == MatchScore2.Text)
        {
            score += 1;
            AmountPoints.Text = score.ToString();
        }
        // nothing correct
        else
        {
            AmountPoints.Text = score.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Any idea's how to check if the forecast has entered the right team to win??
And if the score of a match was a draw the player should also get 3 points, how can I do this?

Comment: 1 - Tag your question properly. 2 - Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in XAML-based technologies. UI is not Data. Learn MVVM, which is the right way to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, move out the numbers of out the textboxes. You should seperate your user interface from your business logic. This will result that you have one function to do the "math" and your user interface will have to call that function. By converting your text to numbers, you can compare these numbers with `<` and `>` to see who has won.

```
int foreCast1 = int.Parse(Forecast1.Text);
int foreCast2 = int.Parse(Forecast2.Text);
int matchScore1 = int.Parse(MatchScore1.Text);
int matchScore2 = int.Parse(MatchScore2.Text);
AmountPoints.Text = DoTheMath(foreCast1, foreCast2, amountPoints1, amountPoints2).ToString();
...
public int DoTheMath(int foreCast1, int foreCast2, int matchScore1 , int matchScore2 )
{
    int score = 0;
    if (forecast1 == matchScore1)
        score++;
    if (forecast2 == matchScore2)
        score++;
    if (matchScore1 > matchScore2 && foreCast1 > foreCast2)
        score += 3;
    if (matchScore1 < matchScore2 && foreCast1 < foreCast2)
        score += 3;
    return score;
}
```